# Trying to use sign extend for a VHDL project and getting error 10500

Tags: mips, vhdl

So I am trying to implement a single cycle MIPS processor in VHDL in my overall file I am trying to sign extend one of the lines however I am getting error 10500 (Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mipsoverall.vhd(57) near text "others";  expecting "(", or an identifier ("others" is a reserved keyword), or  unary operator

Line 57 which I am troubleshooting:

```
    extended_input <= ((sig_instr(15)=>others(31 downto 16)) & (sig_instr(15 downto 0)));
```

This is the code, please let me know if I am going in the right direction or if there are some other changes to be made

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mips_overall is 
    port (clk,reset: in std_logic;
            instruction: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            result: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end mips_overall;

architecture behavior of mips_overall is 
    component reg is 
    port (source_1,source_2,destination: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            write_d: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
            reset,clk,en_write: in std_logic;
         data_1,data_2: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;
    component instr_mem is 
    port (address: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          reset,clk: in std_logic;
            instruction: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;
    component counter is 
    port (increment: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          reset,clk: in std_logic;
            count: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;
    component ALU is 
    port (input1,input2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          clk: in std_logic;
            ALUcontrol: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            beqzero: out std_logic;
            result: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;
    component datamem is 
    port (address,write_data: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
          clk,reset,store_en,load_en: in std_logic;
            read_data: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
    end component;
    signal sig_source1, sig_source2, sig_dest: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
   signal sig_write_d, sig_data1, sig_data2: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   signal sig_instr_address, sig_instr: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   signal sig_increment, sig_count: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   signal sig_input1, sig_input2, sig_result: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   signal sig_alucontrol: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal sig_beqzero: std_logic;
   signal sig_data_address, sig_data_write_data, sig_data_read_data: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal sig_en_store,sig_en_load,sig_en_write: std_logic; --enables connect direcly to control
    signal extended_input: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); --extended signal 
    signal mux1,mux2,mux3: std_logic:= '0';--control signal for mux
        
    begin 
    
    sig_source1<=sig_instr(25 downto 21);
    sig_source2<=sig_instr(20 downto 16);
    sig_input1<=sig_data1;
    extended_input <= ((sig_instr(15)=>others(31 downto 16)) & (sig_instr(15 downto 0)));

    process(mux1,mux2,mux3)
    begin
    if (mux1='0') then 
        sig_dest<=sig_instr(20 downto 16);
    elsif (mux1='1') then 
        sig_dest<=sig_instr(15 downto 11);
    end if;
    
    if (mux3='0') then 
        sig_write_d<=sig_data_read_data;
    elsif (mux3='1') then 
        sig_write_d<=sig_result;
    end if;
    
    if (mux2='0') then 
        sig_input2<=sig_data2;
    elsif (mux2='1') then 
        sig_input2<=extended_input;
    end if;
    end process;
    
    reg_inst : reg
    port map (source_1 => sig_source1,
                  source_2 => sig_source2,
                  destination => sig_dest,
                  write_d => sig_write_d,
                  reset => reset,
                  clk => clk,
                  en_write => sig_en_write,
                  data_1 => sig_data1,
                  data_2 => sig_data2);

    instr_mem_inst : instr_mem
    port map ( address => sig_instr_address,
                  reset => reset,
                  clk => clk,
                  instruction => sig_instr);

    counter_inst : counter
    port map (increment => sig_increment,
                  reset => reset,
                  clk => clk,
                  count => sig_count);

    ALU_inst : ALU
    port map (input1 => sig_input1,
                  input2 => sig_input2,
                  clk => clk,
                  ALUcontrol => sig_alucontrol,
                  beqzero => sig_beqzero,
                  result => sig_result);

    datamem_inst : datamem
    port map (address => sig_data_address,
                  write_data => sig_data_write_data,
                  clk => clk,
                  reset => reset,
                          store_en => sig_en_store,  -- Connect signals
                                  load_en => sig_en_load,  -- Connect signals
                  read_data => sig_data_read_data);

end behavior;
```

The sign extend code isn't working as expected I was trying to use  the MSB of the instruction and use others to fill the rest of the bits. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aggregate concatenated with slice: `extended_input <= (0 to 15 => sig_instr(15)) & sig_instr (15 downto 0);` The  aggregate type is from context, "The discrete range has no significance other than to define the set of choices implied by the discrete range." "Each element of the value defined by an aggregate must be represented once and only once in the aggregate." Tells us the aggregate length is 16. In -2008 an aggregate alone `extended_input <=(31 downto 16 => sig_instr(15), 15 downto 0 => sig_instr(15 downto 0));` an association can be of the type of the aggregate as well it's elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from the incorrect use of `others` in the assignement. `others` is used to assign all values of a specific array (or the remaining, unassaign bits)  to the same value. `Others` cannot have an array constraint. You need to define an aggreage to then assign others to. So in your case, you want the top 16 bits to be the sign bit. Like this:

```vhdl
extended_input <= (31 downto 16 => (others => sig_instr(15)) & sig_instr(15 downto 0);
```

Here the aggregate is formed by defining an array with the `31 downto 16` range and assigning all bits the sign bit of `sig_instr`.

You would be much better off using the `signed` type from `numeric_std` package, then you can use the resize function:

```vhdl
signal extended_input  : signed(31 downto 0);

...

extended_input <= resize( signed(sig_instr(15 downto 0)), extended_input'length) );
```

The `resize` function does the sign extension for you.

Comment: I am getting Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mips_overall.vhd(59) near text ";";  expecting ")", or "," for the first option

Answer (score 0):

Your use of aggregate notation is wrong (see your favorite VHDL book for the syntax). In your case you can try:

```vhdl
extended_input(15 downto 0) <= sig_instr(15 downto 0);
extended_input(31 downto 16) <= (others => sig_instr(15));
```

In VHDL 2008 the 2's complement signed extension is implemented by the `ieee.numeric_std.resize` function with signature:

```vhdl
function RESIZE (ARG : UNRESOLVED_SIGNED; NEW_SIZE : NATURAL) return UNRESOLVED_SIGNED;
```

So, as you use `ieee.numeric_std`, and if you also use VHDL 2008 (see your tools options to declare that if it's not already the default), you could also try:

```vhdl
extended_input <= std_logic_vector(resize(u_signed(sig_instr(15 downto 0)), 32));
```

We need two type conversions here:

1. `u_signed(sig_instr(15 downto 0))` to convert from `std_logic_vector` to `UNRESOLVED_SIGNED` (`u_signed` is a shorter alias for `UNRESOLVED_SIGNED`)
2. `std_logic_vector(...)` to convert the result back to `std_logic_vector`.

Note: you should use `std_ulogic_vector` and `std_ulogic` (unresolved types), not `std_logic_vector` and `std_logic` (resolved subtypes of the former). You don't want resolved types in your case. If you don't understand the difference always use the unresolved types (that's what the `u` means in `std_ulogic`) until, one day maybe, you will really need a resolved type for a good reason.

Using resolved types by default everywhere is like jumping without a parachute. It could be that some people (professor, manager...) or tools ask you to use resolved types by default, instead. Try to resist (but don't get sacked for this), they are wrong and probably don't understand the difference neither.